# How to change the font style for table view cell text

Tags: iphone, ios

In my coding the table view cell text style could not be changed. How can i change the style for text in table view cell. please any one can help.

Comment: cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"custom" size:12.0f]

Comment: If you want to change the label font in your storyboard check out my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
```

Add any font you want. And if you are adding a UILabel then simply use its properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRoman" size:30];
```

Set font using this line of code....

Comment: sorry its not worked for me. size only changed but style will not changed.

Comment: set differant format and try.... what error are shown log it...

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard you can select your label on the cell and go to the attributes inspector. Next to font select the font you want.

Comment: programmatically creating this table view cell but style not changed.